# Calculation of sigma with Gaussian distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

I am looking for a Gaussian function centered in $0$ with $90\%$ of the integral is in $[-10,10]$. From this information, how can I get the value of $\sigma$?

I guess we can write $P(|X|<10)=0.9$

$\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{1/2}\sigma}\int_{-10}^{10}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx=0.9$

Then

$\frac{1}{\sigma}\int_{-10}^{10}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx=0.9*(2\pi)^{1/2}$

But I cannot conclude...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\sigma=1$, then $P(|X_1|<1.644854...)=0.9$. So in order to get $P(|X_{\sigma}<10)=0.9$ you just have to calculate $\sigma=\frac{10}{1.644854...}$. The point is that $\sigma$ stretches the quantiles away from the center of the distribution. Due to the special nature of $\Phi(x)$, you can't calculate the exact $\sigma$ by hand.

Comment: Thx. I am not sure why it works. I'll try to find out myself. Then I will validate the answer :)

Comment: Increasing the standard deviation parameter is equivalent to increasing the absolute value of each realisation by exact the same amount. Thus the quantiles follow.